# how to run games or apps within one project --iPhone/iPad/iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I want to add a game into my current project, the game and my current project are two separate projects, so how could I combine them to one?

I have thought of two possible solutions:

1. Merge the source code. But I don't want to do this, as it's so much trouble and very cumbersome.
2. Packaging the game into `.app` or `.ipa`  or `.a` or something else, then import this game package to project, but I don't know how to run it with Objective-C code.

In fact, the second method is described below.

```
NSWorkspace *workspacce = [NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace]; 
NSString * appPath = [[workspacce activeApplication] objectForKey:@"NSApplicationPath"];
appPath = [appPath stringByDeletingLastPathComponent]; 
appPath = [appPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"/CSVEdit.app"];
[workspacce launchApplication:appPath];
[[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] launchApplication:@"a`enter code here`ppName"] ;
```

Does anyone have a more effective or simple solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think merging is the only option. Because it's not allowed to launch another App.

```
Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected
```

Chapter 2 Functionality point 2.8 written in the [terms](http://images.worldofapple.com/appstoreguidelines_9910.pdf).

Comment: if I choose the merging ,do you know any code skills to do this ?   as a game , you know the "appDelegate" files is complex ,can i create the object of the appdelegate in my project directly?  or merging the two files?  thank you !!